# How do I add options from a module page to <select> list in CKeditor dialog?

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

I'm trying to get list values from drupal .module page to ck-editor Plugin.js file iam getting this error
https://snag.gy/ah3Poz.jpg

in my module.module page i have written

```
function agilecrm_getConfig(Editor $editor) {
  return [
    'pluginName_options' => $this->buildOptions()
  ];
}

in Plugin.js file


CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'simpleLinkDialog', function( editor )
{
    return {
        title : 'Page',
        minWidth : 200,
        minHeight : 150,
        contents :
        [
            {
                id : 'general',
                label : 'Settings',
                elements :
                [
                   {
                        type : 'select',
                        id : 'style1',
                        label : 'Landing Pages',
                        items: editor.config.pluginName_options,
                        required : true,
                        commit : function( data )
                        {
                            data.style1 = this.getValue();
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };
});
```

Please any one help me